# Recompile C Program under different name

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, centos6, configure

I am extending an open source project (which is currently installed and running on a Centos 6 server), but I am using a local Centos 6 machine for development.

Quick question, how would I compile the new version on my real server, without affecting (or worse overwriting), the current installation on Centos?

I presume this is as simple as compiling to a different name, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this with ./configure make make install etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try executing `./configure --help` first. It may contain information about setting prefix for path to install and names of executables, which should be helpful for putting multiple version of software on one system.

Comment: Any well-behaved program will, by default, install into `/usr/local` and, as such, will not interfere with any properly packaged application. You might use the manually compiled one by default though which might *look* like interfering.

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT, that's helped me quite a bit as well as opening a whole load of other useful information